# Intelligencia URL Rewrite for child application

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

Alright, looks like I could use some help again...

Currently, I'm working on merging three applications under a single sign-on. One application is custom, the other is YAF and the third is the Screwturn wiki. Currently, the custom and YAF applications are successfully integrated using YAF's sample web application and seems to work just fine.

The problem I'm currently running into is the Intelligencia URL Rewriter that comes with YAF. It's redirecting /Account/Login.aspx (my original login) correctly to YAF's as intended and even redirects the likes of /FreddyKrueger/Login.aspx to the correct login. But when I go to a secure page in Screwturn, I get redirected to this: /Wiki/PageNotFound.aspx?Page=forum .

And my best guess is that it's rewriting to this: /Wiki/Forum.aspx?login=stuff which Screwturn then reinterprets as the above, when, I believe, I need it to rewrite to this: /Forum/Login.aspx.

At this point, I'm not sure if this is a rewrite issue, a child application issue or, more likely both.

Once again, any and all clues would be greatly appreciated as this is all volunteer work and I've been burning a huge amount of time trying to figure this out. I'm not heavily experienced in URL rewriting or regular expressions.

URL Rewrite config follows:

`<rewriter>
  <!-- Handle Standard Logins -->
  <if url="^((?!forum).)*$">
    <rewrite url="^~/(.+?)?login?\.aspx(\?(.+))?$" to="~/forum/forum.aspx?g=login&amp;$2" processing="stop" />
  </if>
  <rewrite url="^~/forum/forum\.aspx\?g=login(&amp;(.+))?$" to="~/forum/forum.aspx?g=login&amp;$1" processing="stop" />
  <!-- Standard URL Rewriting Format -->
  <rewrite url="^~/Wiki/(.+?)?yaf_login?\.aspx(\?(.+))?$" to="~/$1Forum.aspx?g=login&amp;$3" processing="stop" />
  <rewrite url="^~/(.+?)?yaf_login?\.aspx(\?(.+))?$" to="~/$1Forum.aspx?g=login&amp;$3" processing="stop" />
  <rewrite url="^~/(.+?)?yaf_info?\.aspx\?i=([0-9]+?)&amp;url\=(.+)$" to="~/$1Forum.aspx?g=info&amp;i=$2&amp;url=$3" processing="stop" />
  <rewrite url="^~/(.+)?yaf_topics([0-9]+)p([0-9]+)(_([\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Nd}\p{Pc}-]+))?\.aspx(\?(.+))?$" to="~/$1Forum.aspx?g=topics&amp;f=$2&amp;p=$3&amp;$7" processing="stop" />
  <rewrite url="^~/(.+)?yaf_topics([0-9]+)(_([\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Nd}\p{Pc}-]+))?\.aspx(\?(.+))?$" to="~/$1Forum.aspx?g=topics&amp;f=$2&amp;$6" processing="stop" />
  <rewrite url="^~/(.+)?yaf_forum([0-9]+)(_([\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Nd}\p{Pc}-]+))?\.aspx(\?(.+))?$" to="~/$1Forum.aspx?g=forum&amp;c=$2&amp;$6" processing="stop" />
  <rewrite url="^~/(.+)?yaf_postst([0-9]+)find([-a-z]+)(_([\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Nd}\p{Pc}-]+))?\.aspx(\?(.+))?$" to="~/$1Forum.aspx?g=posts&amp;t=$2&amp;find=$3&amp;$7" processing="stop" /> 
  <rewrite url="^~/(.+)?yaf_postst([0-9]+)p([0-9]+)(_([\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Nd}\p{Pc}-]+))?\.aspx(\?(.+))?$" to="~/$1Forum.aspx?g=posts&amp;t=$2&amp;p=$3&amp;$7" processing="stop" />
  <rewrite url="^~/(.+)?yaf_postst([0-9]+)(_([\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Nd}\p{Pc}-]+))?\.aspx(\?(.+))?$" to="~/$1Forum.aspx?g=posts&amp;t=$2&amp;$6" processing="stop" />
  <rewrite url="^~/(.+)?yaf_postsm([0-9]+)find([-a-z]+)(_([\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Nd}\p{Pc}-]+))?\.aspx(\?(.+))?$" to="~/$1Forum.aspx?g=posts&amp;m=$2&amp;find=$3&amp;$7" processing="stop" />
  <rewrite url="^~/(.+)?yaf_postsm([0-9]+)(_([\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Nd}\p{Pc}-]+))?\.aspx(\?(.+))?$" to="~/$1Forum.aspx?g=posts&amp;m=$2&amp;$6" processing="stop" />
  <rewrite url="^~/(.+)?yaf_profile([0-9]+)(_([\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Nd}\p{Pc}-]+))?\.aspx(\?(.+))?$" to="~/$1Forum.aspx?g=profile&amp;u=$2&amp;$6" processing="stop" />
  <rewrite url="^~/(.+)?yaf_rsstopicft([0-9]+)t([0-9]+)(_([\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Nd}\p{Pc}-]+))(_([\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Nd}\p{Pc}-]+))?\.aspx(\?(.+))?$" to="~/$1Forum.aspx?g=rsstopic&amp;ft=$2&amp;t=$3&amp;$9" processing="stop" />
  <rewrite url="^~/(.+)?yaf_rsstopicft([0-9]+)f([0-9]+)(_([\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Nd}\p{Pc}-]+))(_([\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Nd}\p{Pc}-]+))?\.aspx(\?(.+))?$" to="~/$1Forum.aspx?g=rsstopic&amp;ft=$2&amp;f=$3&amp;$9" processing="stop" /> 
  <rewrite url="^~/(.+)?yaf_rsstopicft([0-9]+)(_([\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Nd}\p{Pc}-]+))(_([\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Nd}\p{Pc}-]+))?\.aspx(\?(.+))?$" to="~/$1Forum.aspx?g=rsstopic&amp;ft=$2&amp;$8" processing="stop" />
  <rewrite url="^~/(.+)?yaf_([-0-9a-z_]+?)\.aspx\?(.+)?$" to="~/$1Forum.aspx?g=$2&amp;$3" processing="stop" />
  <rewrite url="^~/(.+)?yaf_([-0-9a-z_]+?)\.aspx$" to="~/$1Forum.aspx?g=$2" processing="stop" />
  <!-- Advanced URL Rewriting Format -->
  <rewrite url="^~/(.+?)?error.aspx$" to="~/$1error.aspx" processing="stop" />
  <rewrite url="^~/(.+?)?install/default.aspx?(\?(.+))?$" to="~/$1install/default.aspx?$2" processing="stop" />
  <rewrite url="^~/(.+?)?install/$" to="~/$1install/default.aspx?$2" processing="stop" />
  <rewrite url="^~/(.+?)?login?(\?(.+))?$" to="~/$1forum.aspx?g=login&amp;$3" processing="stop" />
  <rewrite url="^~/(.+?)?info?\?i=([0-9]+?)&amp;url\=(.+)$" to="~/$1forum.aspx?g=info&amp;i=$2&amp;url=$3" processing="stop" />
  <rewrite url="^~/(.+)?topics/([0-9]+)-(([\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Nd}\p{Pc}-]+))?(/page([0-9]+))(\?(.+))?$" to="~/$1forum.aspx?g=topics&amp;f=$2&amp;p=$6&amp;$7" processing="stop" />
  <rewrite url="^~/(.+)?topics/([0-9]+)-(([\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Nd}\p{Pc}-]+))?(\?(.+))?$" to="~/$1forum.aspx?g=topics&amp;f=$2&amp;$6" processing="stop" />
  <rewrite url="^~/(.+)?/category/([0-9]+)-(([\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Nd}\p{Pc}-]+))?(\?(.+))?$" to="~/$1/forum.aspx?g=forum&amp;c=$2&amp;$6" processing="stop" />
  <rewrite url="^~/(.+)?posts/t([0-9]+)findlastpost-(([\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Nd}\p{Pc}-]+))?(\?(.+))?$" to="~/$1forum.aspx?g=posts&amp;t=$2&amp;find=lastpost&amp;$7" processing="stop" />
  <rewrite url="^~/(.+)?posts/t([0-9]+)findunread-(([\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Nd}\p{Pc}-]+))?(\?(.+))?$" to="~/$1forum.aspx?g=posts&amp;t=$2&amp;find=unread&amp;$7" processing="stop" />
  <rewrite url="^~/(.+)?posts/t([0-9]+)-(([\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Nd}\p{Pc}-]+))?(/page([0-9]+))(\?(.+))?$" to="~/$1forum.aspx?g=posts&amp;t=$2&amp;p=$6&amp;$8" processing="stop" />
  <rewrite url="^~/(.+)?posts/t([0-9]+)-(([\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Nd}\p{Pc}-]+))?(\?(.+))?$" to="~/$1forum.aspx?g=posts&amp;t=$2&amp;$6" processing="stop" />
  <rewrite url="^~/(.+)?posts/t([0-9]+)?(\?(.+))?$" to="~/$1forum.aspx?g=posts&amp;t=$2&amp;$5" processing="stop" />
  <rewrite url="^~/(.+)?posts/m([0-9]+)findlastpost-(([\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Nd}\p{Pc}-]+))?(\?(.+))?$" to="~/$1forum.aspx?g=posts&amp;m=$2&amp;find=lastpost&amp;$7" processing="stop" />
  <rewrite url="^~/(.+)?posts/m([0-9]+)findunread-(([\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Nd}\p{Pc}-]+))?(\?(.+))?$" to="~/$1forum.aspx?g=posts&amp;m=$2&amp;find=unread&amp;$7" processing="stop" />
  <rewrite url="^~/(.+)?posts/m([0-9]+)-(([\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Nd}\p{Pc}-]+))?(\?(.+))?$" to="~/$1forum.aspx?g=posts&amp;m=$2&amp;$6" processing="stop" />
  <rewrite url="^~/(.+)?profile/([0-9]+)-(([\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Nd}\p{Pc}-]+))?(\?(.+))?$" to="~/$1forum.aspx?g=profile&amp;u=$2&amp;$6" processing="stop" />
  <rewrite url="^~/(.+)?admin/([\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Nd}\p{Pc}-]+)?/([\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Nd}\p{Pc}-]+)?(\?(.+))?$" to="~/$1forum.aspx?g=admin_$2_$3&amp;$5" processing="stop" />
  <rewrite url="^~/(.+)?admin/([\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Nd}\p{Pc}-]+)?(\?(.+))?$" to="~/$1forum.aspx?g=admin_$2&amp;$4" processing="stop" />
  <rewrite url="^~/(.+)?rsstopic/ft([0-9]+)t([0-9]+)-(([\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Nd}\p{Pc}-]+))(_([\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Nd}\p{Pc}-]+))?(\?(.+))?$" to="~/$1forum.aspx?g=rsstopic&amp;ft=$2&amp;t=$3&amp;pg=$5&amp;$7" processing="stop" />
  <rewrite url="^~/(.+)?rsstopic/ft([0-9]+)f([0-9]+)-(([\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Nd}\p{Pc}-]+))(_([\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Nd}\p{Pc}-]+))?(\?(.+))?$" to="~/$1forum.aspx?g=rsstopic&amp;ft=$2&amp;f=$3&amp;pg=$5&amp;$7" processing="stop" /> 
  <rewrite url="^~/(.+)?rsstopic/ft([0-9]+)-(([\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Nd}\p{Pc}-]+))_([\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Nd}\p{Pc}-]+)(\?(.+))?$" to="~/$1forum.aspx?g=rsstopic&amp;ft=$2&amp;pg=$3&amp;$7" processing="stop" />
  <rewrite url="^~/(.+)?rsstopic/ft([0-9]+)-(([\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Nd}\p{Pc}-]+))-([\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Nd}\p{Pc}-]+)(\?(.+))?$" to="~/$1forum.aspx?g=rsstopic&amp;ft=$2&amp;pg=$3&amp;$7" processing="stop" />
  <if url="^((?!\.ashx|\.asmx|\.axd|\.gif|\.png|\.jpg|\.ico|\.pdf|\.css|\.js|install|error|auth\.aspx|default\.aspx|popup\.aspx|advanced\.aspx|digest\.aspx).)*$">
    <rewrite url="^~/forum/(.+)?\?(.+)?$" to="~/forum/forum.aspx?g=$1&amp;$2" processing="stop" />
    <rewrite url="^~/forum/(.+)?$" to="~/forum/forum.aspx?g=$1" processing="stop" />
    <rewrite url="^~/forum/(.+)?\.aspx$" to="~/forum/forum.aspx?g=$1" processing="stop" /> 
  </if>
</rewriter>`

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be an inheritance issue. By instructing the Wiki not to inherit from the parent application, the wiki stops trying to reinterpret the redirect to a login page as one of it's own wiki pages.